# How to use javascript or jquery to read a single value in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

suppose I have a function：

```
    function getLayerInfo(uuid, top, left, index, pindex) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.top = top;
        this.left = left;
        this.index = index;
        this.pindex = pindex;
    }
```

then I use json menthod in json.js:

```
    var layer = new getLayerInfo('abc', 123, 456, 4, 5);
    var layerjson = layer.toJSONString();
    console.log(layerjson );
```

It have show the correct result,

So if I want restore the json to array or something else,or what should I do?
Or what I want is just need the "index" property value?

What should I do? 
Thank you

Comment: what do you mean *"restore the json to array"*?

Comment: What exactly is the issue at hand here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using jQuery do this:

```
var result = $.parseJSON(layerjson);
```

jQuery is recommended because it will use the best and fastest method to parse the JSON string (First trying to run browser parser and then, if unavailable, javascript/built in parsers)

if not using jQuery just run this (it uses browser parser, but be careful with older browsers, make sure it exists):

```
var result = JSON.parse(layerjson);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.parse` on your `layerjson` variable:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(layerjson);
alert(obj.index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .parseJSON() method to convert the string back to object.

var layerObj = layerJSON.parseJSON();

layerObj.index will give you the value of the property.